# Installing laravel 5 in not empty directory

Tags: git, laravel-5.1

How do you install laravel in a not empty directory ? I have some files in a certain directory and they are using version control. Now i want to install laravel in the same directory and put those files in the public directory. My git repository cannot change.

Comment: Show us your effort, what problems did you have?

Comment: What about "git clone https://github.com/laravel/framework.git public"?

Comment: I cloned my repo with one file. Lets say file.txt I think i cannot clone two repos.

Comment: My solution was to install laravel in another folder and just copy the files.